# iOS Facebook SDK highscore story is not being displayed on user's timeline

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an iOS game and I want to post highscore stories into user's Facebook timeline. 
I'm issuing a POST request to the scores api passing app access token and also the score. The method return true which, as stated in developers documentation, means that the score has been posted successfully.

The problem is that even that method seems to be working right, the highscore story never gets displayed on user's timeline. I'm aware that not all stories will be posted, but there wasn't even a single one I was able to see there. So it is not working.

The app is setup as a native iOS app under Games category.

Is there anything else I need to setup on app settings to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you solved it somehow?

Comment: Some of them do get posted, but it took a while until I was able to see them in user's timeline. So it was working properly in my case.

Comment: After sending like 15 scores it finally showed. All good.